# Size class wCompact|hAny gets overridden by wCompact|hRegular

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, size-classes

I am getting strange behavior with size classes in Xcode 6. I didn't managed to find whether it a bug or documentation misreading.

The thing is: I have to provide different layouts one for iPhone 3.5, 4, 4.7 inch and another for 5.5 inch device.

I've create simple example to demonstrate the bug: the label has 2 constraints - center X and Y within container.
[image]

I've set Y alignment constraint's constant to `100` for `wCompact|hAny` and `-100` for `wCompact|hRegular`.
[image]

The ui looks good in interface builder but not in preview - the `wCompact|hRegular` parameters override `wCompact|hAny`.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm get confused by the information from the popup window that arises in IB when you want to change size of your vc.

[image]
[image]

So is there a way to specify constraints for small iPhones and have different ones for large 5.5 screen?

Comment: Do you have any update on this? I have the same problem. There's an image I want to make bigger for 5.5 in iPhone, but when changing the constraint, wC|hR always overwrites wC|hA. Storyboard displays it fine when switching between different size class, but the preview window is displaying the same size for all iPhone sizes.

Comment: No luck so far with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is the desired behaviour, you choose the Any Width | Any Height combination to make layout decisions that apply to all possible device sizes and orientations, but choose the Compact Width | Regular Height combination to specify layout changes that apply only to sizes resembling iPhone devices in portrait orientation.

So `Compact Width | Any Height` parameters will overwrite `Any Width | Any Height` parameters  for iPhone devices in portrait and landscape orientation. `Compact Width | Regular Height` parameters will overwrite `Compact Width | Any Height` parameters for iPhone devices in portrait orientation. General rule is specific size class overwrite more general ones. In your case, if you rotate to landscape orientation, the label origin Y is above the center's origin Y with a distance of 100, which has not been overwritten.

Comment: Well, you may notice a green-blues dots that appear in different positions while you selecting your sizes. wC|hR is more speficic than wC|hA - Don't you think it should apply __only__ to iphone 5.5 but not for all others? I thought it is pretty obvious and intuitively expected...

Comment: You mean wC|hR should only applied to iPhone 5.5? The hint says it applies to all iPhones in portrait, while wR|hC only applies to 5.5 inch iPhones in landscape. I don't know why. From that, I think you can put a different constraints for 5.5 screen in landscape.